# Visually represent two-dimensional decomposition

Tags: data-visualization

Lets say i have the decompositions of a financial result into 21 portfolios and 11 asset classes below. I can decompose the result into either portfolios or asset classes easily by using a waterfall chart (which my bosses really love), but I am looking for something, hopefully similar, which can decompose both dimensions simultanously.

|  | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | P7 | P8 | P9 | P10 | P11 | P12 | P13 | P14 | P15 | P16 | P17 | P18 | P19 | P20 | P21 | Total A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | -120 | -100 | -75 | -395 | -76 | 24 | -2 | -2 | -10 | 0 | -216 | -46 | -1 | -18 | -2 | -26 | -10 | -4 | 0 | -9 | -6 | -1094 |
| A2 | 99 | 36 | 18 | 19 | 1 | 92 | 7 | 6 | 16 | 0 | 2 | 18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 321 |
| A3 | 75 | 23 | 12 | 8 | 0 | 62 | 5 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 208 |
| A4 | 82 | 55 | 34 | 160 | 24 | 103 | 10 | 8 | 6 | 0 | 26 | 25 | 1 | -8 | -1 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 4 | 551 |
| A5 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | -8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| A6 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| A7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A8 | 28 | 3 | -1 | -8 | 0 | 56 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 12 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 96 |
| A9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | -1 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| A11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Total P | 173 | 24 | -10 | -210 | -52 | 343 | 21 | 17 | 22 | 0 | -184 | -3 | 1 | -13 | -2 | -18 | -9 | 9 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 113 |

Comment: What do you mean by `decomposition`? What are you decomposing and why?

Comment: @user2974951: the table contains a "Total" row and column, so the OP presumably would like to visualize how the separate entries contribute to these two-dimensional totals.

Comment: Are you looking for a *spineplot*?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a heatmap with the data except for the totals, and add a separate row and column next to the heatmap showing the totals. This does not really capture the "decomposition" aspect, but it should at least draw attention to particularly high or low values. (Just be careful to actually use black body radiation colors rather than, say, [rainbow colors](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4118486/) - see also [here](https://xkcd.com/2537/).)

[image: heatmap]

R code (which I am not overly proud of; see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46091522/452096):

```
dataset <- structure(c(-120, 99, 75, 82, 7, 2, 0, 28, 0, 1, 0, 173, -100, 
36, 23, 55, 5, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 24, -75, 18, 12, 34, 1, 1, 0, 
-1, 0, 1, 0, -10, -395, 19, 8, 160, 2, 0, 0, -8, 0, 4, 0, -210, 
-76, 1, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -52, 24, 92, 62, 103, 6, 
2, 0, 56, 0, -1, 0, 343, -2, 7, 5, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 
-2, 6, 4, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, -10, 16, 10, 6, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -1, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -216, 2, 
0, 26, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, -184, -46, 18, 6, 25, -8, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, -3, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -18, 0, 0, 
-8, 1, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, -13, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, -2, -26, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -18, -10, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -9, -4, 4, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -9, 2, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 3, -6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1094, 321, 
208, 551, 17, 7, 0, 96, 0, 7, 0, 113), dim = c(12L, 22L), dimnames = list(
    c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", 
    "A11", "Total P"), c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", 
    "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P13", "P14", "P15", 
    "P16", "P17", "P18", "P19", "P20", "P21", "Total A")))


blackBodyRadiationColors <- function(x, max_value=1) {
    # x should be between 0 (black) and 1 (white)
    # if large x come out too bright, constrain the bright end of the palette
    #     by setting max_value lower than 1
    foo <- colorRamp(c(rgb(0,0,0),rgb(1,0,0),rgb(1,1,0),rgb(1,1,1)))(x*max_value)/255
    apply(foo,1,function(bar)rgb(bar[1],bar[2],bar[3]))
}

plot(c(0,ncol(dataset)+2),c(0,nrow(dataset)+2),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",type="n",
    xlim=c(0,ncol(dataset)+2),ylim=c(1,nrow(dataset)+2))
axis(1,at=1:(ncol(dataset)+1),labels=c(head(colnames(dataset),-1),"",tail(colnames(dataset),1)))
axis(2,at=rev(1:(nrow(dataset)+1)),labels=c(head(rownames(dataset),-1),"",tail(rownames(dataset),1)),las=1)

for ( ii in 1:(nrow(dataset)-1) ) {
    for ( jj in 1:(ncol(dataset)-1) ) {
        rescaled_value <- 0.2+0.6*(dataset[ii,jj]-min(dataset))/diff(range(dataset))
        rect(jj-0.5,nrow(dataset)-ii+1.5,jj+0.5,nrow(dataset)-ii+2.5, col=blackBodyRadiationColors(rescaled_value),border=NA)
        text(jj,nrow(dataset)-ii+2,dataset[ii,jj],col=ifelse(rescaled_value>0.5,"black","white"))       
    }
    rescaled_value <- 0.2+0.6*(dataset[ii,ncol(dataset)]-min(dataset))/diff(range(dataset))
    rect(ncol(dataset)+0.5,nrow(dataset)-ii+1.5,ncol(dataset)+1.5,nrow(dataset)-ii+2.5, col=blackBodyRadiationColors(rescaled_value),border=NA)
    text(ncol(dataset)+1,nrow(dataset)-ii+2,dataset[ii,ncol(dataset)],col=ifelse(rescaled_value>0.5,"black","white"))
}
for ( jj in 1:(ncol(dataset)-1) ) {
    rescaled_value <- 0.2+0.6*(dataset[nrow(dataset),jj]-min(dataset))/diff(range(dataset))
    rect(jj-0.5,0.5,jj+0.5,1.5, col=blackBodyRadiationColors(rescaled_value),border=NA)
    text(jj,1,dataset[nrow(dataset),jj],col=ifelse(rescaled_value>0.5,"black","white"))     
}
```